# Counting Occurrences In A Map

Tags: c++

Currently writing a program that will parse through a directory (using the boost library) and add file extensions, the number of that specific type of file, and the files size to a map that includes a string and the key being a class. I am now trying to find the total number of occurrences for each file extension, the total number of files that were found in the directory and the total number of bytes found in the directory.

Here is the important code:

```
class fileStats
{
public:
    int totalFiles;
    long long fileSize;
};

map< string, fileStats > fileMap;

fileMap[dirIter->path().extension()].totalFiles++;
fileMap[dirIter->path().extension()].fileSize += file_size( dirIter->path());
```

I don't think I can use the .count method of maps, unless I overload it, but is there another simpler way of doing it?

Comment: You can count occurrences in O(n) if you keep a count while iterating over the map. But if you use a different data structure in the first place you may have better results

Comment: If you must calculate the total amount using some logic, you can iterate your map and then use boost::accumulator when yuour elements matches your conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, looks like you have everything readily available. Total number of extensions is

```
fileMap.size()
```

Then you can iterate of this map printing number of files and byte count

```
for (auto i=fileMap.begin(); i!=fileMap.end(); ++i)
    cout << i->first << '=' << i->second.totalFiles << ':' << i->second.fileSize << endl;
```

Here is the test program that prints totals.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class fileStats
{
 public:
  int       totalFiles;
  long long fileSize;

  fileStats() : totalFiles(0), fileSize(0) {}
  fileStats(int f, long long s) : totalFiles(f), fileSize(s) {}

  fileStats& operator+=(const fileStats&  other)
  {
    totalFiles += other.totalFiles;
    fileSize   += other.fileSize;
    return *this;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  typedef std::map< std::string, fileStats >  map_type;

  map_type fileMap;

  fileMap["cpp"].totalFiles++;
  fileMap["cpp"].fileSize += 11111;

  fileMap["h"].totalFiles++;
  fileMap["h"].fileSize += 22222;

  fileMap["cpp"].totalFiles++;
  fileMap["cpp"].fileSize += 33333;

  fileStats totals;
  for (map_type::const_iterator i=fileMap.begin(); i!=fileMap.end(); ++i)
    totals += i->second;

  std::cout << "total files=" << totals.totalFiles << ' ' << "total size=" << totals.fileSize << std::endl;

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: Okay well that solves finding the number of extensions, but how would I find the a total of the totalFiles and then a total of the byte count? Basically I just want to add the totalFiles per extension together to know the total number of files in the directory, and then add all the bytes together to get the total for that.

Comment: Added trivial totals computation.